# Push to another view from main component React Router 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am new to react and the react router. What I try to achieve is doing an AJAX call and after that I would like to go to another component/page. I am used to Vue and with Vue you got something like `this.$router.push('/page')`. So I tried to find something similiear but I am still not sure if it is possible because I find so many different answers/questions. I tried to look it up in the docs but didn't succeed.

My main component (little adjustments due the long code)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class Main extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.AddIcecream = this.AddIcecream.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            icecreams: {}
        }

    }

    componentDidMount() {

        axios.get('/api/icecreams').then(response => {
            this.setState({
                icecreams: response.data
            });
        });


    }


    AddIcecream(product) {

        product.price = Number(product.price);
        /*Fetch API for post request */
        fetch('/api/icecreams/', {
            method: 'post',
            /* headers are important*/
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },

            body: JSON.stringify(product)
        })
            .then(response => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                //update the state of products and currentProduct
                this.setState((prevState) => ({
                    icecreams: prevState.icecreams.concat(data),
                    currentProduct: data
                }));

                //Push to another component here

            })

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Router}>
                <div className="container">

                    <div className="row justify-content-center dashboard-header">
                        <div className="col-md-12">
                            <h2><i className="ion-ios-home-outline"></i> Dashboard</h2>
                            <h3>Welcome, Glenn</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="row">

                        <div className="col-md-3">

                            <div className="sidebar-router">

                                <ul>
                                    <li className="active"><Link to="/home/">Icecreams</Link></li>
                                    <li className="active"><Link to="/home/orders">Orders</Link></li>
                                </ul>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div className="col-md-9">

                            <Route exact path="/home/" render={() => <Icecreams icecreams={this.state.icecreams} loadIcecreams={this.loadIcecreams} />} />
                            <Route exact path="/home/edit/:id" render={(props) => <Edit {...props} icecreams={this.state.icecreams} />} />
                            <Route exact path="/home/add" render={() => <Add AddIcecream={this.AddIcecream} />} />

                            <Route exact path="/home/orders" render={() => <Orders orders={this.state.orders} />} />



                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </Router>
        );
    }
}

if (document.getElementById('root')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
}
```

What is the best way to handle the 'redirect' to another component after completing an AJAX request and how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
import {withRouter, ....restofimports} from 'react-router-dom'
 class Main extends Component {
//code...
}
```

By using withRouter your class now has acess to the routers props, the one you need is history. This allows you to navigate across your application.

```
const WithRouterApp = withRouter(App);
```

Where you would usually render App

```
render(
  <Router>
    <WithRouterApp />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Now use the setState call back and `this.props.history.push` to change pages.

```
axios.get('/api/icecreams').then(response => {
            this.setState({
                icecreams: response.data
            }, () => this.props.history.push('/somepage'));
        });
```

Comment: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` with both the callback as just a test function that runs If I click on a button..

Comment: add the comma after the bracket

Comment: I noticed that one already but doesn't seem to work either. Also, just if do `<button onClick={() =>  this.props.history.push('/somepage')}`>Test</button>` I get the same error.

Comment: did you do export default withRouter?

Comment: Yes I did. No luck.

Comment: figured out your problem

Answer (score 0):

you can use react router for that but you have to request for it first from the context API so in your component you have to request for the router

you have to import the prop-types library like this

`import * as PropTypes from "prop-types";`

 and the next code put it inside the component like a method or a property 
     
    `static contextTypes = {
     router: PropTypes.object
   };`

and then you can use the router APi in your component in your promise success function as you mentioned you can push to another route with this code 

`this.context.router.history.push("<YOUR_ROUTE_HERE>");`

if your ajax call completed successfully you will be redirected the the route you choose .

Comment: Please give more context where to add the Proptypes etc.

Comment: sorry about that you have to install a library called prop-types and then import it